# How do I write subquery sql for multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

Let say there is Part table. 
I first select Part table with query and it returns 500 rows. 
After distinct (partid), I get 100 only.

> > select count(distinct partid) from Part where partname iLike 'ABC%';

Now, I need to loop partid (uniq) , and query 'PartAlt' table to fetch 'alternatepartid'. And this table has 'partid' so I can join.

For each loop, I will get 10 or so but I only need 'alternatepartid' from these rows.

> > select alternatepartid from PartAlt where mpnid = xxx 
> >     So, at the end of loop, I will have 1000 alternatepartid.

Now, for each loop of these results, I take alternatepartid and join / query with the first 'Part' table above.

So, this is joining a table to get multiple rows in itself.

how do I write this using subquery and/or join ?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the below query should take your first query (without count) and use it as a subquery that is joined to the other table with the partid column:

```
select PartAlt.alternatepartid from 
  (select distinct partid from Part 
     where partname iLike 'ABC%') as uniq_parts 
join Part as PartAlt on uniq_parts.partid = PartAlt.mpinid;
```

You can also use a cte, (`with .. as`), which is sometimes easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to what `select distinct` and `join`.  One method is:

```
select distinct alternatepartid
from Part p join
     PartAlt pa
     on pa.partid = p.partid
where p.partname iLike 'ABC%';
```